# property as NSManagedObject in view controller for a "current NSManagedObject"

Tags: objective-c, core-data, properties, nsmanagedobject

I am interested in setting a property as a subclass, say Person, of NSManagedObject in a view controller that will specify an instance of person so that I will be able to update with methods in the controller. can I do it like this?

```
// Viewcontroller.h

@implementation

@property (nonatomic, retain) Person* currentPerson;

@end

// ViewController.m

@implementation

@dynamic currentPerson;

-(void) doSomethingToCurrentPerson {
    currentPerson.SomeAtrribute=somevalue;
}  

@end
```

It seems like if this were not a valid way to go, it would also be possible to set a unique identifier and then store CurrentPersonUniqueID as a property and use KVC. Is there a way to get something along the lines of what I posted to work, or am I better off with something closer to the KVC approach, or something totally different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code won't work until you replace `@dynamic` by `@synthesize`. `@dynamic` tells the compiler that `-setCurrentPerson:` and `-currentPerson` are implemented somewhere else, which is not the case.

So `@synthesize currentPerson` will create the `currentPerson`'s getter/setter automatically. It won't have anything to do with the fact that `Person` is a `NSManagedObject`.

Also, either you can't access to `currentPerson` directly with this name, you have to use its getter:

```
self.currentPerson.attribute = something;
// or
[self currentPerson].attribute = something;
```

**Correct code:**

```
// Viewcontroller.h
@implementation    
@property (nonatomic, retain) Person* currentPerson;
@end

// ViewController.m
@implementation
@synthesize currentPerson;

-(void) doSomethingToCurrentPerson {
    self.currentPerson.SomeAtrribute = somevalue;
}

@end
```

Comment: the `@synthesize` is not necessary with the latest compiler... it's assumed

Comment: Also, I prefer using the accessor: `self.currentPerson`, but if you had added `@synthesize currentPerson = _currentPerson`, you could access person as an _ivar_: i.e. `_currentPerson`

Comment: can I change the property to (nonatomic, strong) as I would for an NSObject subclass?

Comment: @nielsbot: according to [the objective-c doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW9), `If you do not specify either @synthesize or @dynamic for a [...] property, you must provide a getter and setter [...].`. Is it outdated ?

Comment: I see. I never used xCode before ARC, so strong is all I know. As I am learning about CoreData I am seeing some (retain) pop up and I just used it because I had seen it in code.

Comment: @LoïsDiQual: It's new in Xcode 4.4. Look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW110), under "Compiling: LLVM2.0"